# Spring @Transactional not working in few cases

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, transactional

I have my following service class annotated with `@Transactional`.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public Order acceptOrder(Order inputOrder) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(inputOrder);
        session.close();
        return inputOrder ;
    }

    public Order updateOrder(Order inputOrder) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        //session.beginTransaction();
        if(inputOrder.getOrderStatus().equals("confirmed")) {
            EmpAccount empAcc = (EmpAccount)session.get(EmpAccount.class, inputOrder.getEmpId());
            double newEmpBal = empAcc.getAvailable_balance() - inputOrder.getOrderAmount();
            empAcc.setAvailable_balance(newEmpBal);
            System.out.println("new bal"+newEmpBal);

            VendorAccount venAcc = (VendorAccount)session.get(VendorAccount.class,inputOrder.getvId());
            double newVenBal = venAcc.getBalance() + inputOrder.getOrderAmount();
            venAcc.setBalance(newVenBal);
            session.update(inputOrder);
        //  session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }

        return inputOrder;
    } }
```

For `acceptOrder()` , `@Transactional` is working and i have a new row created in db , but when `updateOrder()` is called no changes in db are reflected .

Can someone tell me why is this ? TIA

Comment: It isn't working for for both cases. Never use `openSession` when using Spring with Spring managed transactions. Instead use `getCurrentSession` and remove the call to `session.close()`.

Comment: alright noted , working now thanks , can you please explain me why you said it is not working when I called `acceptOrder()` , coz there we used `openSession` as well and it made an update in DB

Comment: It did an insert and it runs outside the scope of a transaction. It runs outside the scope because you are obtaining an unmanaged session with `openSession`. It works because it is an insert and not an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by M. Deinum , for Spring managed Transactions , no need of opening and closing the `Session` , `Session` is provided by `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`